# What is the difference between Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url and Zend_View_Helper_Url?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, controller, helper

I'm currently using ZF 1.12.2, and I'm using the URL action helper to set action attributes on my form, but the action helper is performing an array to string conversion.  I have commented on what I am being returned below:

```
<?php
// application/modules/user/controllers/SignupController.php

class User_SignupController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = new User_Form_Signup();

        // This gives me 'user/signup/Array'
        $signup_url = $this->_helper->url(array(
            'module' => 'user',
            'controller' => 'signup',
            'action' => 'register'
        ));

        // This gives me 'user/signup/register', which is what I want
        $signup_view_url = $this->view->url(array(
            'module' => 'user',
            'controller' => 'signup',
            'action' => 'register'
        ));

        $form->setAction(...);
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {

    }
}
```

I don't really understand why this is happening.  I have examined both Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url and Zend_View_Helper_Url and their methods are similar:

```
// get the front controller's router
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter(); 

// assemble the route
return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
```

I have just discovered mid-question that `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url::simple` will solve my needs, but I'm still confused and curious about what I am being returned above.

How can the router assemble two completely different routes (one being totally wrong) from two separate calls on the same object's method using the same argument?  I have not added any routes in the bootstrap nor in my config as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `$this->_helper->url` actually returns the class. When you call action helpers in this way with parameters, the parameters are passed to the `direct()` method on that helper. In this case, the `direct()` method takes up to three arguments, the first of which should be the action name. So the reason you're having problems is that the helper is expecting an action name to be supplied, but you're supplying an array.

What you actually want is to call the `url()` method on the helper:

```
$this->_helper->url->url(array(
    'module' => 'user',
    'controller' => 'signup',
    'action' => 'register'
));
```

Personally I normally use the 'other' syntax for calling action helpers in controllers:

```
$this->getHelper('url')->url(array(
    'module' => 'user',
    'controller' => 'signup',
    'action' => 'register'
));
```

which I find a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you.  All of the method overloading can get a bit hairy for me.